# CakePHP: newly saved record invisible to find()

Tags: php, cakephp, caching, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

My controller needs to create/save one or more records by looping over the request data it receives and creating corresponding records. You may be wondering: why not just use `saveAll()` and save them all at once. The short answer is that certain records need to reference the ID of *other* records created in the same loop (and those IDs don't exist yet).

My loop creates the first record successfully, subsequent iterations of the loop are unable to "see" that newly created record when I use `find()`. If I echo the returned array, results are there, but the newly created one is missing. **Why?** Is CakePHP's magic making the new record unavailable due to some sort of caching?

Here is my code that doesn't include the newest record:

```
$newest_parent_question = $this->Question->find('first', array(
                                                            'conditions'=>array('Question.perm_id'=>$parent_question['Question']['perm_id']),
                                                            'order' =>  array('Question.created DESC')
                                                            ) 
                                                );
```

However, the new record IS returned with this:

```
$newest_parent_question = $this->Question->find('all');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something wrong with your query.

Likely the `$parent_question['Question']['perm_id']` is wrong.  There's nothing CakePHP will do that would make your record un-find-able.

Just debug your variables to make sure you're building the correct query with the correct id, and you'll be good to go.

(without seeing the actual way you're building the id, it's impossible to help beyond that)